# Cannot remove extra steps from Illustrator action

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

I am new to Adobe Illustrator.

I created a few actions by recording. Somewhy when I record the action Reflect in vertical, AI adds strange parameters Origin DX and Origin DY with some values. So when I use this action, my object together with reflecting jumps far away, which is very uncomfortable. I want to reflect on the same place.

But I cannot delete these Origin DX and Origin DY by clicking the trash icon, it does nothing. And I tried to record this action again several times, it always adds Origin DX and Origin DY. How can I avoid them or delete them?

Illustrator CC.

[image: action]

Comment: I just tested it and do not get the same issue as you. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBm28.png What steps did you take when recording your action? If just right clicking on an object and selecting transform > reflect it shouldn't record the origin. Edit: My test was run on CC 2018. If you're on a different version it might be a bug.

Comment: I use CC2015 and it records the reference point in the Transform panel. I use an action for years and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to rotate or reflect any object - any reflection/rotation - there **must** be an origin -- a point that is seen as the "pivot point" where the center of the reflection/rotation resides.

It is illogical, if not impossible, to want a rotation/reflection *without* an origin point. You **can't** remove the origins. Not having them would not allow any reflection/rotation.

---

**However...**

You should be able to use *relative* positioning, i.e. "flip horizontal/vertical" which would reflect using the center of the object as the *relative* origin.

It depends a bit on *specifically how* you are rotating/reflecting.

If an object is selected on the artboard, **double-clicking** the **Rotation** or **Reflection** tool will open a pop up dialog. Simply input the desired change there and click `OK`. That will use the center of the object as the origin point. -- You could also merely alter values on the **Transform Panel** or **Control Bar**.

I believe it's only when using the *tools* to "click" and set a point of origin that the origin is recorded into an action. **Using the dialogs boxes or panels won't record a point of origin specifically.**